# What's the alternative of layout_above in ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I've tried `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/the_view_which_will_remain_below"` but it's not the desired output. 
I want the same behavior from RelativeLayout's `layout_above`.

With this code my Textview starts appearing from the bottom and as the character increases texts goes above. But I want the texts to start from starting of parent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context="com.fatimamostafa.restfulwebservices.asynctask.AsyncTaskRequest">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Run" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Clear" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/ll"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:textSize="160sp"
        android:text="Text"
      />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Just to understand, you want the text at the top of the parent and the linearlayout at the bottom of the parent right?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want. @Juan

Comment: `layout_above` is simply `layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf` in `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: That's what I used. But didn't get the desired result until I added `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"` @LalitSinghFauzdar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put the text at the top of the parent and the LinearLayout at the bottom contraint the top of the text view to parent and un-constraint it from the the LinearLayout:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textSize="160sp"

    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

     />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
   >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Run" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Clear" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have removed some constraints that I think were redundant.

Also note you can put the TextView obove the LinearLayout using "@+id" instead of @id.

If you want to constraint the text floating between the parent top and the Linear layout add these constraints to the TextView, and adjust the vertical bias between 0 and 1.

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ll"
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **height** **0dp** and **organize** views vertically.

in **relative** **layout** we can use layout below and above like

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        />
```

In **constraint** **layout** giving height is compulsory so you can give 0 height. and then you can set your view below other views like this

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tablayout" />
```

you can use **constraintTop_toBottomOf** and **constraintBottom_toTopOf** properties to adjust your view to above or below of other. 
thanks